# Difference between SourceSet and SourceDirectorySet, Gradle

Tags: gradle

Just like the question title says. I found the following example in the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
   main {
      java {
         exclude 'some/unwanted/package/**'
      }
   }
}
```

The docs say that `main` is a `SourceSet` and `java` is a `SourceDirectorySet`. The distinction still isn't that clear to me, though. Is a `SourceSet` just a container for `SourceDirectorySet`s? What else can a `SourceSet` contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the answer can be found in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html):

> A **SourceSet** represents a logical group of Java source and
> resources.

while,

> A **SourceDirectorySet** represents a set of source files composed
> from a set of source directories, along with associated include and
> exclude patterns.

What it means is that `SourceSet` is just a logical unit that groups `SourceDirectorySet`s.